# Chrome resizeto function size

Tags: google-chrome

I have a requirement to resize my window upon say a button click and then again get back to the initial 
size.
However in chrome(maybe other browsers as well) i am hitting this issue that calling open with a width and then using resizeTo  with the same width is causing a change in width. Why is this change in size inspite of using the same width. Do ResizeTo and open have different meaning of the width parameter??

```
 myWindow=window.open('','','width=300,height=200');
   myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'myWindow'</p>");
   myWindow.focus();
   setTimeout(myWindow.resizeTo(300,200), 10000);
```

​
http://jsfiddle.net/AdbTk/

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle it works http://jsfiddle.net/yD8Cc/

**EDIT**

resize function is getting executed right when the setTimeout is set, moreover you will not notice the change because you are setting the same height and width again!

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  But my question here is even if i am setting the same width and height again, why is there a change in size when changing from "open" to "resizeTo" ?